# how can I insert one row into hive table with partition?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to insert one row into tb_table,but it seems that hive not support that.

My sql:

```
insert into tb_test values('000','111') partition (day='20190404');
```

Exception:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 missing EOF at 'partition' near ')'

Comment: try this insert into tb_test values('000','111') partition day='20190404';

Comment: actually,it not works. still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Insert statement should be like,

```
insert into tb_test partition(day='20190404') values('000','111');
```

Order of partition columns should be same as they appear in the PARTITION() clause in table create statement.

In case of INSERT INTO SELECT statement, dynamic partition columns must be specified last among the columns in the SELECT statement.

Please refer [Hive Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries) for more information.